# Range expressions in Elm

Tags: elm

Elm supports `[1..100]`, but if I try `['a'..'z']`, the compiler gives me a type mismatch (expects a number, gets a Char). Is there any way do make this work?

Answer (score 21):

Just create a range of numbers and map it to chars:

```elm
List.map Char.fromCode [97..122]
```

*Edit*, or as a function:

```elm
charRange : Char -> Char -> List Char
charRange from to =
  List.map Char.fromCode [(Char.toCode from)..(Char.toCode to)]

charRange 'a' 'd' -- ['a','b','c','d'] : List Char
```

*Edit*, from elm 0.18 and up, List.range is finally a function:

```elm
charRange : Char -> Char -> List Char
charRange from to =
  List.map Char.fromCode <| List.range (Char.toCode from) (Char.toCode to)
```

Comment: The `[ .. ]` syntax was removed in Elm 0.18, so now you need to replace any instances of `[a .. b]` with `List.range a b`. Note that the type of `List.range` is `Int -> Int -> List Int`, so it also will not work with characters.